# Ajax calls generating URLs with RESEND

Tags: google-analytics

I set up Google Analytics on my PHP website. Since I want to track the ajax calls I make as separate URLs, I added code below for them (targetURL is defined earlier in the Javascript function):

**ga('set', 'page', targetURL);**

**ga('send', 'pageview');**

This has worked for a while, but now I'm noticing something new. In some (relatively few) instances I get an analytics entry with no targetURL but the word RESEND followed by a number. It's been almost always RESEND1. The Avg Time on Page for these pages has been close to the site average.

We have no such page or Ajax call as RESEND1, and I'm at a loss to explain the entries. Any ideas?

Comment: can you post your definitions for targetURL

Comment: targetURL is just a normal URL for the site absent the domain, so **/create.php** or **/customer/edit.php**